# Multiple output in Vite build for React app and separate scripts in project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, build, bundle, vite

I have a frontend project. This has two contexts, the /authentication context is a react app and the /home context, which is typescript scripts.
I'm having trouble building with vite. I want the common build of react plugin to be done for /authentication, and /home to do it separately.
At the end of the dist I would like to have an /auth folder with your js and css, and another /home folder with your js.

The main.txs, I only have it so I can run the react project locally. But it should be ignored in the package.
Inside each folder, /home and /auth there is a file main.ts which is the entry point.

[image]

Expect result:

```
/dist
   /authetication
       index.js
       index.css
   /home
       index.js

   ... public files
```

Build with vite:

```
/dist
   /authetication
       index.js
       index.css
   /home
       index.js

   ... public files
```